# Would the diode and the fuse protect the other components if power wiring is reversed?

Tags: diodes, schematics, fuses, schottky

Would the diode and the fuse protect the other components if power wiring is reversed?
Is the polarity of the diode correct?

[image: Would the diode and the fuse protect the other components?]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Have you tried to simulate it or test it?

Comment: 3557-2 is a fuse holder; the actual value of the fuse to be installed is extremely important here.

Comment: You have to make sure the fuse blows before the diode smokes, but when polarity is correct the fuse should not blow due to inrush current from the 270µF+1500µF capacitors. Difficulty level increases with capacitance. This means you need to look at the time-current curves in the fuse datasheet...

Comment: Schematic convention is to put positive voltages at the top and GND at the bottom.

Comment: @MarlonOtto not sure if serious oO, Poe's law is strong here. Assuming you are. Fuses are just pieces of metal, they are not polarised

Comment: A fuse does not have polarity, but, as already pointed out, its value can be critical.

Comment: Oupps i ment the diode

Comment: then yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal operating conditions the diode D3 is reverse biased with only a small leakage current passing through it.

If the input polarity is reversed the diode will conduct to minimize the voltage and protect the following circuitry.

The forward voltage will depend upon the current available from the source - it could be about 1V at 30A. The following circuitry would probably not be damaged with only 1v of reverse voltage. The fuse needs to be rated to blow within a short time at this current.

[image: Forward voltage]

[SS24 Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/SS24-D.PDF)